# MySQL storage engine for a large log table

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, myisam

(I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349752/mysql-storage-engine-for-log-table) but it's not specific enough for what I want to ask.)

I'm setting up a large-ish (a hundred GB or so) log table with an average record size of 100-200 bytes and several indexes (indices?).  Insertion rate will be about 100-200 records per second.  I will run analytical queries on this table, probably not all of them will hit a suitable index so they might run for a long time and look up a lot of data.

1. What storage engine would you suggest?  (Basically MyISAM vs InnoDB.)
2. If using MyISAM, will long queries block inserts?
3. Table size is a concern (not a big one, but still).  In this respect, is one engine more efficient than the other?
4. Performance-wise, how do they compare?
5. Is there anything else I must be aware of in this situation?

Comment: Did you consider other solutions? Our experience with storing large log files in a relational database aren't very good. Either a NoSQL solution or maybe even a dedicated full-text search engine might be better.

Answer (score 7):

if you use INSERT and UPDATE high performance uses InnoDB over MyISAM is better.
and if you use more SELECT statements before the INSERT / UPDATE uses MyISAM.
  The InnoDB has support with ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation and Durability) therefore the more SELECT and JOIN is slower but is faster for INSERT.

EYE: If you need to transact such a payment gateway, you should use InnoDB has transaction support