# java servlet inserting data into mysql db with composite key

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I'm working on a servlet that needs to insert some data to the db table with a composite primary key consists of the userid, dataid and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.
however im getting the following error when executing the query

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry'13-7-2013-09-13 23:22:24' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I think this is caused by the multiple insertion of rows to the same table in the same time, though with different dataid. Is there any solution to this problem? Should I cancel `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a part of the primary key to do the trick or there are some other better workarounds?

Thanks a lot and appreciate for any help!

Comment: can't you have an auto increment key at database level ?

Comment: Check that the table is actually configured how you think it is. That error message makes me suspect the key is not actually a composite key.

Comment: @FredClose well actually both userid and dataid are foreign key and auto increment will be done when new rows inserted into their respective tables

Comment: @TomG I checked in phpmyadmin three fields are actually marked primary, i think it is a composite key then? Actually I have used the php to access the same database and do the same operation before, it was smooth and with no errors, maybe its the way java handle insertion different from php?

Comment: It appears that your "timestamp" is hour:min:sec.  This guarantees duplicates if you attempt to insert more than 1 row per second.  Consider adding millisecond.

Comment: turns out it's just my looping logic of the servlet for the queries goes wrong... anyway appreciate for all your helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a **log table**, it is recommended not to use a primary key. If you want to accelerate some search in this table, create the appropriate indexes.

If you need a primary key (for example, if you plan to use it with JPA), it would be best to use a number, e.g.

```
ID int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

For example, log4j can insert each event log into a database using a [`org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/jdbc/JDBCAppender.html).

See also [*MySQL storage engine for a large log table*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516888/mysql-storage-engine-for-a-large-log-table).

Comment: You mean don't use primary key at all? And yes this is kinda like a log table but with some deletion on the rows as well. So i think using a separate auto increment key may make things more complex?

Comment: Do you want to delete records that are older than a date? No problem. From a user? No problem. For the dataid? Neither. Combinations? ... You do not need a primary key. You need indexes.