# It is more efficient to use hybrid Mysql storage engine (innoDB+MyISAM) for log files?

Tags: mysql, logging, storage, innodb, myisam

I am planning a centralize log server, which receiving syslog from many devices (up to 2000).
It should have ability to query & sort events.

I have read [Mysql storage engine for log table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349752/mysql-storage-engine-for-log-table)

Since MyISAM is better on selecting, while InnoDB is better on writing. How about using hybrid engine   to gain different benefit ?

1. Use innoDB for writing, to get benefit from row-locking.
2. Use MyISAM for read-only ancient log.
3. Use Merge to split large table into many smaller tables.

Here are the steps:

1. Create InnoDB table A, syslog-ng will insert row to it when receiving log.
2. Create MyISAM table named 'yyyymmdd' every midnight, move rows from table A to it. The data will keep persistently.
3. Using a table with merge engine, merge each 'yyyymmdd' for query operation.

Considering both query and write, is it more efficient strategy than using a single innoDB/MyISAM table?

Comment: I know it's not answer you expected but I would recommend ElasticSearch. Very robust for storing and querying huge amounts of data, it's quite popular log storage solution.

Comment: Also I think you don't really understand the difference between MyISAM and InnoDB. Latter is faster with updates because of row-locking mechanism (as opposed to table lock in MyISAM) however MyISAM is considered way faster if you just want to insert a lot of data and only read later.

Comment: In my environment, the inserted row will never be modified later. So I think row-locking mechanism only get benefit on concurrent insert. Maybe enlarge the buffer of syslog-ng is another strategy when table-locking ?